# spring integration outbound sftp channel adapter file delivery confirmation

Tags: spring-integration

We are using sftp channel adapter to send files to sftp server. Is there any way to confirm whether file is delivered or not?
What we are facing is sometime a dropped connection between our server and sftp server and we like to know and retry if file transfer was not successfull.

Answer (score 1):

Actually everything in the `FileTransferringMessageHandler` is done sequentially.
So, I'm sure you are facing one of the exceptions in your logs:

```
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    throw new MessageDeliveryException(message, "File [" + inputStreamHolder.getName()
                + "] not found in local working directory; it was moved or deleted unexpectedly.", e);
}
catch (IOException e) {
        throw new MessageDeliveryException(message, "Failed to transfer file ["
                + inputStreamHolder.getName() + " -> " + fileName
                + "] from local directory to remote directory.", e);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    throw new MessageDeliveryException(message, "Error handling message for file ["
                + inputStreamHolder.getName() + " -> " + fileName + "]", e);            
}
```

The `<int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter>` supports `<request-handler-advice-chain>`, where one of them can be `<retry-advice>` (or `MessageHandlerRetryAdvice` bean reference) to meet your requirements.

Please, find more info in the [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain).

Comment: Exception we are getting is from sftp lib where it says "Input stream is closed". Is there any way we can catch this exception and audit them? I also read about errorChannel where this kind of messages being sent. We also need some way to track if file has been transferred successfully.

Comment: Consider to use `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` at the same place as `MessageHandlerRetryAdvice` (or instead). Read the same Reference Manual chapter.